# How to test class methods from outside the class in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to test each method in a class, from another module.  So here is the class.

```
#newmodule

class test:
    def atest(a,b):
        return a

    def btest(a,b):
        return b
```

and in the other module, I am attempting to do:

```
import unittest
import newmodule
test.atest(5,4).assert not errors
test.atest(7,9).assert not errors
```

Note:  I'm sure there are all sorts of errors here, but I just mocked this up as an example.  The main question I have here is how to successfully import newmodule and test each METHOD.  I suspect that there are complications with trying to test methods from outside of the class as opposed to just testing functions.

I am already failing right off the bat because I am getting:

```
ImportError: no module named newmodule
```

even though they are in the same directory.

How do I successfully import this module and if so, am I able to test the methods from outside the class?

Comment: It should be named `newmodule.py`, not `newmodule`.  Also, methods should either take the `self` argument, have the `@classmethod` and take the `cls` argument, or have the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

*"even though they are in the same directory."* - its not whether they are in the same directory, its whether `newmodule` is in the current working directory. If you want to run tests from a different directory, you could add your script directory to `sys.path`

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
import unittest
import newmodule
```

This hard-codes which version of your module you are going test test so you have to decide whether that fits your goals. Alternately you could set the `PYTHONPATH` enivronment variable outside of your test script for more flexibility.